# Importing shapefile (.shp) in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.1, illustrator

I am working in ArcGIS, I need to import the shapefiles with all layers, to adobe illustrator.

Can anyone suggest the steps doing this?

Answer (score 10):

Probably the easiest way to get your data into Adobe Illustrator is to go to the file menu and select Export Map.

[image]

From there, Save as Type: AI (*.ai)

[image]

Note the options in the Format Tab.

Alternatively, there is also a paid plugin called **[MAPublisher](http://www.avenza.com/mapublisher)**. It allows you to import the shapefiles directly into Illustrator.  Effectively turning Illustrator into a basic GIS program. I haven't played around with MAPublisher for several years, but it looks like you can import MXDs directly into Illustrator.

Answer (score 0):

Recently ESRI has announced ArcGIS Maps for Adobe Creative Cloud Extension, which allows Adobe Illustrator natively supports GIS file formats, for more details, visit [https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/maps-for-adobecc/mapping/how-to-make-animated-maps/][1]